# Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
       implicit none
       character*20 fflname, oflname, oflname2
       integer      i, length, rn, s(100)
       real*8       phase_shift
       parameter    ( length = 32768, phase_shift = 0.02 )
       real*8       num, real_coeff, imag_coeff
       real*8       amplitude(length), phase(length)
      &            ,imag_coeff_ps(length), real_coeff_ps(length)

       oflname = "wvlt_coeff.data"
       oflname2 = "selection.data"
       fflname = "wvlt_coeff_ps.data"
       open(12, file = oflname)
       do i=1, length
          read(12, *) num, real_coeff, imag_coeff
          real_coeff_ps(i) = real_coeff
          imag_coeff_ps(i) = imag_coeff
       enddo
       close(12)
       open(13, file = oflname2)
       do i=1, 100
          read(13, *) rn
          s(i) = rn
       enddo   
       close(13)    

       do i=1, 100
          amplitude(i) = sqrt( real_coeff(s(i))**2 + imag_coeff(s(i))**2 )
          phase(i) = atan( imag_coeff(s(i))/real_coeff(s(i)) ) + phase_shift
          real_coeff_ps(s(i)) = amplitude(i) * cos( phase(i) )
          imag_coeff_ps(s(i)) = amplitude(i) * sin( phase(i) )
       enddo

       open(15, file = fflname)
       do i=1, length
          write(15, *) i, real_coeff_ps(i), imag_coeff_ps(i)
       enddo
       close(15)

       stop
       end
```

Errors:

```
hyxie@ubuntu:~$ gfortran '/home/hyxie/Documents/20161012/phase_shift2.f' 
/home/hyxie/Documents/20161012/phase_shift2.f:35:40:

          amplitude(i) = sqrt( real_coeff(s(i))**2 + imag_coeff(s(i))**2 )
                                        1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
/home/hyxie/Documents/20161012/phase_shift2.f:36:36:

          phase(i) = atan( imag_coeff(s(i))/real_coeff(s(i)) ) + phase_shift
                                    1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

What is wrong with my coding?

Comment: real_coeff and imag_coeff are declared as scalars but they are used as arrays in your errors. maybe you intended to use the '_ps' variables?

Comment: You probably noticed several people didn't like your question. Please read the help pages about how to ask a good question. There should be some real question within the text, not just your code an an error message. And the title should describe your actual problem. It is irrelevant that you are e beginner, you should describe your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Sincerely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`real_coeff` and `image_coeff` are not arrays, but you are accessing them as if they were. This results in a syntax error. Perhaps you intended to use `real_coeff_ps` and `image_coeff_ps` instead.